# Java: Type out the values of an array

Tags: java, arrays

beginner Java learner here. I need to print out in console all the values of the given array

```
public class ArrayUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2, 5, 8, 10, 32, 22, 11, 66, 12, 30};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, it prints out **[I@1b6d3586** 10 times. Can someone please help me and answer what am I doing wrong and does the output it gives have any meaning? Thanks!

Comment: `System.out.println(array[i]);`

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); - thats all (without the need of for loop)

Answer (score 0):

In order to access each value in the array in the iteration(for loop), you have to specify the index number of the array.

For example, you can replace your print statement with following:

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

More information about array you can refer to Big Java: Early Objects (7th edition is the one I'm currently using) chapter 7.1.2 and 7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

The output you're getting is generated by the standard `java.lang.Object`'s `toString()` method.

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), it's a

> [...] string consisting of the name of the class of which the object
>   is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object [...]

To print out the individual elements of the array, you'll have to change your print statement to:

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach [Enhanced for Loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/), (the For-Each Loop) ( >= Java 5)

```
    int[] array = {2, 5, 8, 10, 32, 22, 11, 66, 12, 30};

    for(int i : array){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array object reference to System.out each time you iterate.

You can either change `System.out.println(array)` to `System.out.println(array[i])` to print the integer at each index.

Or, You could simply use Java's [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to print the contents of the array like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2, 5, 8, 10, 32, 22, 11, 66, 12, 30};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the array. Not the values of array. So you have to change below line:

```
System.out.println(array);
```

To:

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

You can use For-each loop as below:

```
public class ArrayUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2, 5, 8, 10, 32, 22, 11, 66, 12, 30};
        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays class from Collection framework to do that like this,

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

also you can iterate the array in traditional way.

```
for(int i : array) {
   system.out.println(i);
}
```